# Accessing Qubit With DAGCircuit

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I'm currently trying to make my own TransformationPass to use when compiling a QuantumCircuit for specific hardware, but I'm struggling to get things to work with the DAGCircuit that gets passed to the `run(self, dag)` method that gets overridden. My main issue at the moment is trying to figure out which qubits each node in the graph actually operates on. I can access the wire for each node, but accessing the qubit index from there raises a DeprecationWarning.

I can simply ignore the warning, but it gives me the impression that I should be going about this another way.

Is there a formal method for accessing the qubit (either object or simply its index) given the DAG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `DAGCircuit` right now there isn't a great answer for this. The `.index` attribute is deprecated as in the case of standalone bit objects on the circuit if they're in a register it might not yield the result you expect (it'll be the register index not the index on the circuit necessarily).

I typically do this by having something like:

```py
dag_qubit_map = {bit: index for index, bit in enumerate(dag.qubits)}
```

and then I can get the index with a dict look up, something like:

```py
bit_index = dag_qubit_map[node.qargs[0]]
```

On the `QuantumCircuit` class there is a `.find_bit()` method which does this easily: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.find_bit.html

so you can do:

```py
bit_index = QuantumCircuit(bit).index
```

But an equivalent API is still needed for the DAGCircuit class.

Comment: Thanks, seems a bit weird that there isn't a way to do this automatically. Accessing node.qargs wasn't working for me (probably because I have the DAG nodes and not the gates), but replacing qargs[0] with wire worked fine